# bat script hangs when run from Process.Start()

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have the following C# code:

```
private void executeBat(string batfile)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(batfile);
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.ErrorDialog = false;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
    p.WaitForExit();
    if (p.ExitCode != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("bat script failed with exit code " + p.ExitCode + ".");
    }
    p.Close();
}

string batFile = @"C:\Data\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder\SomeBat.bat";
executeBat(batFile);
```

That runs a .bat script that looks like this:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\SomeThirdParty\SomeExe" >C:\Data\SomeLog.txt 2>&1
set exitcode=%errorlevel%
echo "error return is %exitcode%" >>C:\Data\SomeLog.txt
exit /b %exitcode%
```

The SomeLog.txt file looks like this:

```
"error return is 0"
```

But it appears that the .bat does not really exit because the c# code never returns from p.WaitForExit().

Other people have experienced this problem but my report is different because I am not reading stdout or stderr.

This does not happen consistently.  Perhaps 1 out of 1000 executions.

Here is a big clue...
It only happens when I run the c# code from Task Scheduler.  When I run it from the commandline I have never gotten the issue.

Comment: Show us the value of `batfile` you are passing in.

Comment: Thank @Mofi, I fixed the typo in my sample.

Comment: It was a typo in my simplified sample.  The method in the real code is identical, the calling of the method is a bit more complex.  The code will run 1,000 times without a problem, then it will hang and wait to be killed by timeout in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Hm, I think the cause of this issue occurring only rarely must be searched in `SomeExe`. It looks like this executable sometimes does not terminate gracefully. You could modify the batch file to write first into the log file current date/time, next append the output of `SomeExe`, then append again current date/time and finally append the exit code of `SomeExe`. Perhaps you can see with the two additional date/time lines if `SomeExe` sometimes does not terminate itself at all or randomly takes much longer than usually.

Comment: I put the echo in the code to test that the .exe is returning; adding the time into the echo is a good idea to see if the .exe is hanging.  I will do that report what I find.